# Generate targets with MSBuild then import them in same session

Tags: import, msbuild

I have an MSBuild project file that generates some of its own targets, then imports them. It works nicely, except that `msbuild` has to be run twice to do the build—once to generate the rules and again for them to be visible to finish the build. (The logic was ported from a `Makefile` that itself only needed one run.)

Is it possible to run the generating target, *then* `Import`, *then* run one of the generated targets?

The following listing is a trivialized version of the actual use case which exhibits the same behavior. (Beside the point, the actual case generates targets from a list of filenames of the pattern `*-to-*.xsl`, using the name to automatically determine the dependency and destination.)

The objective is to make `msbuild /t:SecondTarget` work on the first try instead of requiring a second.

```
<Project
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
  InitialTargets="AdditionalTargets"
  ToolsVersion="4.0">

  <!--
    A trivial target-generating task. Presume something more useful for
    the actual case.
  -->
  <UsingTask
    TaskName="GenerateAdditionalTargets"
    TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory"
    AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
    <ParameterGroup>
      <Result ParameterType="System.String" Output="true"/>
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Reference Include="System.Xml"/>
      <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq"/>
      <Using Namespace="System"/>
      <Using Namespace="System.Xml.Linq"/>
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs"><![CDATA[
          var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003");

          var collected = new XElement(ns + "Project",
            new XAttribute("ToolsVersion", "4.0"),
            new XElement(ns + "Target",
              new XAttribute("Name", "SecondTarget"),
              new XElement(ns + "Message",
                new XAttribute("Text", "1.21GW?!")
              )
            )
          );

          Result = collected.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
        ]]></Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <AdditionalTargets>additional.targets</AdditionalTargets>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="AdditionalTargets">
    <GenerateAdditionalTargets>
      <Output TaskParameter="Result" PropertyName="Targets"/>
    </GenerateAdditionalTargets>
    <WriteLinesToFile File="$(AdditionalTargets)" Lines="$(Targets)" Overwrite="true"/>
  </Target>

  <Import Project="$(AdditionalTargets)" Condition="Exists('$(AdditionalTargets)')"/>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. By design when calling a task it does not have the entire context of the project. It just has what is passed in to it. It's designed this way (*at least one reason*) so that task invocations cannot have unforeseen consequences which are hard to identify.

Comment: Frustrating as this was, all applicable targets had to be generated and then explicitly forwarded with `<MSBuild/>` tasks from the main project. It's a good thing there weren't very many. :-/