# Is it possible to import an msbuild target where its location is property defined in a target?

Tags: msbuild

is there a way to use an Import directive in msbuild such that the value of the Project property is a variable, and that variable is defined in a target?

As it stands, it seems to me that Import directives are evaluated before any targets.

For instance:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <PublishDir>none</PublishDir>
        <AutomatedTestsTarget>none</AutomatedTestsTarget>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="GetPublishDir">
        ...
    </Target>

    <Target Name="BeforeCompile" DependsOnTargets="GetPublishDir">
        <PropertyGroup>
            <AutomatedTestsTarget>$(PublishDir)\automated_tests.build</AutomatedTestsTarget>
        </PropertyGroup>
    </Target>

    <Import Project="$(AutomatedTestsTarget)"/>

</Project>
```

**Frankensolution**

Quick solution (as per comment), two msbuild calls, first writes a file. Second does the import this way (by reading the path from the file):

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AppRootDir>$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\directory.txt))\..\automation\</AppRootDir>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I solved this with two msbuild calls; the first writing a file - containing the path - to disk. The second call reads the file and retrieves the publish directory that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Imports happen during the "evaluation phase", and not the "execution phase".

> During the evaluation phase of a build... imported files are incorporated into the build in the order in which they appear...  Properties are defined and modified in the order in which they appear.
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997067.aspx

You may be able to split your configuration gathering & execution into separate msbuild projects, with one calling  the other.

ie: [Generate targets with MSBuild then import them in same session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482762/generate-targets-with-msbuild-then-import-them-in-same-session/13619032#13619032)